# Is there a easier way of running an android application using the eclipse emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to write an android application and my workflow is as follows:

1. Write some code
2. Click run as Android Application
3. Eclipse then starts the android emulator
4. Install the app on the emulator
5. Run it

It seems to me that there is no need for it to start an android emulator(3) each time and to kill it. It'd be nice if there was a way an android emulator always running and eclipse just installs/uninstalls the app instead of making me wait every time.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, don't close the emulator -_-

Comment: I had the same issue when I started developing android :)

Comment: Haha same; it's so intuitive to just close the emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, it just does that way - leave emulator on, and "run" in Eclipse will update the app and run it. This is how it works for me.

Just don't kill the emulator!